# flake8 F403 explicitly testing import *

Tags: python-3.x, flake8

```py
from xx import *
```

may be an anti-pattern for code (though not necessarily interactive use). But one of the uses of **init**.py is to specify my library exports. So of course I want to test it.

flake8 naturally reports errors:

```
F403 'from xx import *' used; unable to detect undefined names
F405 'roughly' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: xx.f
```

Simply disabling the warning seems heavy-handed, is there a better way? Ideally a way which lets flake8 do its job on subsequent tests?

I don't want to also add pylint as an additional process step:
[Make flake8 differentiate between undefined functions and star imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56265620/make-flake8-differentiate-between-undefined-functions-and-star-imports)

Comment: perhaps test the contents of `__all__` instead of running a `*` import -- or use an inline `# noqa: F403` on the offending line? (disclaimer: current flake8 maintainer)